# scala error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do this for matrix multiplication of two large matrices in scala. Below is the logic for the multiplication:

```
val res = M_.map( M_ => (M_.j,M_) )
    .join(N_.map( N_ => (N_.j, N_)))
    .map({ case (_, ((i, v), (k, w))) => ((i, k), (v * w)) })
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map({ case ((i, k), sum) => (i, k, sum) })
```

`M_` and `N_` are two RDDs of these two classes:

```
case class M_Matrix ( i: Long, j: Long, v: Double )
case class N_Matrix ( j: Long, k: Long, w: Double )
```

But I am getting the following error:

[Error image-Please open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFUf1.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add more of the code to the question. How do you create the `M_` and `N_` matrices and the definition of `M_Matrix` and `N_Matrix`. I added what I believe  is the correct definition (from another question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your rdd/dataframe contains `M_Matrix` and `N_Matrix` objects you can not match with a tuple. Something like this should work:

```
val res = M_.map( M_ => (M_.j,M_) )
    .join(N_.map( N_ => (N_.j, N_)))
    .map{ case (_, (m_matrix, n_matrix)) => ((m_matrix.i, n_matrix.k), m_matrix.v * n_matrix.w)}
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map{ case ((i, k), sum) => (i, k, sum)}
```

---

A better solution than using the case classes would e to use `MatrixEntry`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry
```

Use it instead of `M_Matrix` and `N_Matrix` when building the RDDs, then the `join` can look like this:

```
val res = M_.map( M_ => (M_.j,M_) )
    .join(N_.map( N_ => (N_.i, N_)))
    .map{ case (_, (m_matrix, n_matrix)) => ((m_matrix.i, n_matrix.j), m_matrix.value * n_matrix.value)}
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map{ case ((i, k), sum) => MatrixEntry(i, k, sum)}
```

This will result in a `RDD[MatrixEntry]`, same as the two that were joined.

Comment: is this the correct way to build the rdd?                                                   **val M_ = sc.textFile(args(0)).map{ line =>
  val a = line.split(",")
  MatrixEntry(a(0).toLong, a(1).toLong, a(2).toDouble)
}**

Comment: @AvinashGayam If you have a csv file as input to the method it should work. Did out try?